# solution to the PDE $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x} + i\frac{\partial f}{\partial y} = g$? where g is k times continuously differentiable function

Tags: partial-differential-equations

How can I find the solution (in $C^k$) to the complex PDE $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x} + i\frac{\partial f}{\partial y} = g$? where g is (1) complex-valued, (2) k times continuously differentiable function and (3) with compact support.

I didn't learn any PDE techniques but this is an exercise in my complex variable text.

Comment: Do you know about the [Cauchy-Riemann equations ?](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Riemann_equations) Else, you can use the [method of characteristics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_of_characteristics) to solve the problem.

Comment: yes and I noticed the expression on the right hand side is the derivative of f in z bar. But how does it related to C-R equation though?

Comment: The equation you asked to solve is exactly the inhomogeneous Cauchy-Riemann equations: and I have deleted my previous comment to your question since I posted my answer to the [same question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3125765/let-h-mathbbc-to-mathbbc-in-ck-mathbbc-with-compact-support-find) asked by another user.